# Simulate UIColor color conversion to iPhone screen

Tags: ios, core-graphics

When I have a standard UIView element with a certain background color, lets say RGB=41,42,46, it gets automatically converted to another color on iOS 10 if it's displayed on screen - here RGB=53,56,60. I have no problem with Apples automatic color conversion.
But when I use the same color to draw in OpenGL, which is far closer to the bare metal, Apple does nothing and 41,42,46 stays exactly 41,42,46. Since I don't want to fight Apples automatic color conversion and assume it would become really messy really fast, I just would like to simulate / calculate Apples color conversion to give OpenGL Apples converted color.

I tried it with CGColorSpace, cgColor.converted, etc. but so far I had no luck. Here's the playground:

```
import UIKit

//let colorSpaceName = CGColorSpace.displayP3
//let colorSpaceName = CGColorSpace.sRGB
let colorSpaceName = CGColorSpace.extendedSRGB
//let colorSpaceName = CGColorSpace.extendedLinearSRGB

let targetColorSpace = CGColorSpace.init(name: colorSpaceName)!

let color = UIColor.init(red: 10/255, green: 20/255, blue: 30/255, alpha: 1)
let cgColor = color.cgColor
let cgColorModel = cgColor.colorSpace
print("Original space: \(String(describing: cgColorModel))")

let convertedCgColor = cgColor.converted(to: targetColorSpace,
                                     intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.perceptual,
                                     options: nil)!
let comps = convertedCgColor.components!
print("Converted: \(convertedCgColor),\n"
    + "\(comps[0] * 255), \(comps[1] * 255), \(comps[2] * 255), \(comps[3] * 255)")
```

I really want to avoid taking screenshots of my UIView's or picture drawing just to get the converted color. There must be a less clumsy solution.

Comment: Does this happen on a plain UIView? It seems strange. Have you found any docs regarding this topic? Are you sure you don’t have semi-transparency on this view? Or maybe translucency, if it is placed on navigation/tab bar?

Comment: can you add color screen shot ? or if you are adding color via storyboard so there are option to change it way like Device color or Adobe Color

Comment: @Losiowaty Not really strange. It's a view in the background with 100% opacity and nothing with color over it. And if I look at it in Xcode's "View UI Hierarchy", I can see right on the "Background" property if I multiply the values with 255 that these are the transformed values. And: I don't modify "backgroundColor" in code.

Comment: @ravi.p Yes, I can change the color space in storyboard, I edit everything in "Generic RGB" and if I select "Display P3" and "sRGB IEC61..." I see the colors which are actually displayed at runtime. That's of course no solution. I need to let the system do the conversion, because they are device dependent. Now there are at least 2 profiles, with iPhone 8 and OLED it may become 3. And maybe Nightshift counts too?